# Pegar nome do Usuario na sessão jsf

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2, spring-security

Estou com dúvida em relação a como pegar o nome do usuário na sessão. Estou utilizando Spring Security 4.2

Tenho minha Classe Usuario

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class Usuario {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String login;
    private String senha;
    private String papel;

}
```

Minha classe UsuarioController

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @Getter @Setter
    private List<Usuario> usuarios;

    @Getter @Setter
    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

}
```

E minha classe SecurityConfig, que faz o papel do filtro, já embutido no Spring Security.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/cliente.jsf").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.jsf")
                .permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/login.jsf?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/cliente.jsf")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.jsf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        List<Usuario> usuarios = usuarioRepository.findAll();

        List<UserDetails> users = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Usuario u: usuarios){
            UserDetails user = new User(u.getLogin(), u.getSenha(), AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_"+u.getPapel()));
            users.add(user);
        } return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);

    }
}
```

Devo criar uma outra classe para resgatar o nome, id do usuário?

Comment: Alguém podes me ajudar? Alguma dica?

Comment: Olá, você pode dar uma olhada [nesse](http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security) material do site Baeldung. Apesar de ser em inglês, olhando para os códigos já dá pra ter uma orientação. Uma outra dica seria procurar no [comentário](http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security/#comment-8324) que, aparentemente, procura saber a mesma coisa que você.